# Installing additional R build tools manually

Tags: r, build, rstudio, build-tools

### tldr;

What exactly does RStudio do when it tells you that you are missing additional build tools and asks you if you would like to install these? As the dialogue is not working, I need to install these manually.

### Complete story

I've recently updated to

- R 3.3.1
- RStudio 0.99.902

And yesterday I noticed that for a little demo project the build process fails. This is what the build console looks like:

[image]

I checked, and it's clearly due to my R project having a `data` directory with an example text file in it.

RStudio tells me I'm missing the additional build tools (I do have the latest/frozen version of Rtools 3.3 installed) and asks me if I want to install these:

[image]

However, when I press `OK`, nothing happens.

Comment: I am having the same issue on mac, cannot figure out what I'm missing. When I click on "yes" I get this error: Error: Could not find tools necessary to compile a package
Call `pkgbuild::check_build_tools(debug = TRUE)` to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The build tools RStudio is referring to is the Rtools compiler toolchain used for Windows systems. You can find them at:

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Given that you are using R 3.3.1, you should prefer [`Rtools33.exe`](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/Rtools33.exe). Normally, RStudio should attempt to automatically download + install Rtools when accepting that dialog; if it's not, that sounds like a bug.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, but that's the Rtools version that I have installed :-/ And RStudio is definitely not continuing with anything after I click OK

Comment: Strange that I get a similar popup when running `brms::brm()` on Linux where _Rtools_ isn't relevant.